# clarification of noobie questions about null and undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I've been attempting to decipher the explanations about *null* and *undefined* in JS, here on stackoverflow and elsewhere. I think I see where a certain amount of miscommunication appears.

For inexperienced developers, when the console tells us that a variable or property is *undefined*, it's the result of an error in coding (example: I forgot to give a value to a variable or return a value from a function). This means that Javascript has assigned *undefined* to the variable or property for me.

As noobies doing tutorials, we're  never asked to explicitly assign *undefined* to a variable.

Now in some example code we see an if statement like 
if (x === *null*) {some code}
and we have no idea why x would equal *null*, or how *null* might have been assigned to x

Most explanations, here on stack overflow and elsewhere, show examples where null is explicitly assigned (ex: var y = *null*). That is, *null* is **not** the result of a coding error, and Javascript does **not** assign *null*. *Null* has to be assigned by the programmer (why they would do that is also a mystery).

Now I have tried to force a script to return *null* by creating an object, setting its properties, and using delete to remove the values of those properties, figuring that would give me:
obj === *null* //true
but I get false (because obj === *undefined* // true)

Also tried this:

```
var A = function(name) {
this.name = name;
}

var a = new A('alpha');
a.name; //'alpha'

A.prototype = {x:23};

a.x; //according to tutorial, this was supposed to have returned *null*, but instead returned *undefined*
```

So the question is, how can I "force a script to return *null*"?.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In javascript, undefined is a value assigned to any variable that is declared but not yet set. People of javascript choosed this approach to separate between variables that are already set and the variables that are only declared. I know you understand this ,I am just trying to say it in a different way. Null is a value that has a type :object. It means a variable that is undefined (no type)can become NULL(an object). Null can come after undefined in time but not the other direction. please to use `typeof` for both of them and check the results to understand the difference

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers  `null` is a javascript primitive data type. It is _not_ an object. `typeof null` returns "object" in the same way `typeof someFunction` returns "function". By historic usage and changing it would break the web. (Functions are of datatype "object" of course)

Comment: *`Null has to be assigned by the programmer (why they would do that is also a mystery)`*: There are plenty of cases where you want to return and thus assign `null`, imho `undefined` should only be implicitly returned(that is returned by a function that does not return anything) while `null` may be a valid return value in cases where the operation returned no results, but may do so in other circumstances.

Comment: So you do have to explicitly assign null. I've seen that a scenario for this would be prototyping a new object. I would guess that you can then add properties (say through a form submisson) to a new instance of the object, then test if the object is still null to find out if the properties took.